# Impossible to merge osm.pbf file properly

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql, osm.pbf, osmium

I've recently started to work on a project with SRTM datas and I've extracted pbf file using `phyghtmap`.

To start I'm getting `hgt` files, converting them to `tif` using the following command : `gdal_fillnodata.py data.hgt data.tif`

Then I'm warping them with `gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 90 90 data.tif warp-90.tif`

And finally creating the pbf file with `phyghtmap --max-nodes-per-tile=0 -s 10 -0 --pbf warp-90.tif`

The results is a list of `pbf` files. They are perfectly fine when I load them into PostGIS with `osm2pgsql`. But I want to merge them to fasten the import.

I've tried all the major solutions:

- `osmium merge *.pbf -o merged.pbf`
- convert `pbf` to `o5m` then `osmconvert64 *.o5m -o=merge.o5m` then convert back to `pbf`
- merging two by two with `osmosis --read-pbf lon4.00_5.00lat44.00_45.00_local-source.pbf  --read-pbf lon5.00_6.00lat44.00_45.00_local-source.osm.pbf --merge --write-pbf osmo_merge.osm.pbf`

None of them worked and the result is only a very small fraction of the data merged in the result file.

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: If I load all pbf with `--append` it works, but it take ages for a very small portion of the world.

Comment: Ok nevermind I found the issue. I wasn't setting the `--start-node-id` and `--start-way-id` in my script. Now I'm assigning unique ID and it work like a charm :)

Comment: Add this as an answer. It will help other people running into the same problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't setting the `--start-node-id` and `--start-way-id` in my script so all my `pbf` was using the same id range. Now I'm assigning unique ID and it work like a charm :)